# A game called "Twerk"

Tags: python, beginner, game, pygame

This my first Python program and game.  Can you please point how I can improve and what code should be changed?

```
import pygame
from pygame import *
import random
import time
import os
import sys
from pygame.locals import *


black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)

pygame.init()

def game():

os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1'
mouse.set_visible(False)

screen = display.set_mode((800,500))
backdrop = pygame.image.load('bg.jpg').convert_alpha()
menu = pygame.image.load('green.jpg').convert_alpha()
ballpic = pygame.image.load('ball.gif').convert_alpha()
mouseball = pygame.image.load('mouseball.gif').convert_alpha()
display.set_caption('Twerk')
back = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())

def text(text,x_pos,color,font2=28):
    tfont = pygame.font.Font(None, font2)

    text=tfont.render(text, True, color)
    textpos = text.get_rect(centerx=back.get_width()/2)
    textpos.top = x_pos
    screen.blit(text, textpos)

start = False
repeat = False
while start == False:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            start = True
            #falling = True
            #finish = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                start = True
    #game over screen
    screen.blit(menu,[0,0])
    pygame.display.set_caption("TWERK")

    #Text
    #"Welcome to Escape"
    #needs replacing with logo 
    text("Twerk",60,white,300)

    #"Instructions"
    text("Instructions",310,white)
    text("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------",320,white)
    text("Avoid the the enemies",340,white)
    text("Last as long as you can!",360,white)
    text("Press space to start",420,white)
    pygame.display.flip()


while start == True:
positionx=[]
positiony=[]
positionxmove=[]
positionymove=[]
falling = False
finish = False
score=0
enemies=4
velocity=1

for i in range(enemies):
  positionx.append(random.randint(300,400)+random.randint(-300,200))
  positiony.append(random.randint(200,340)+random.randint(-200,100))
  positionxmove.append(random.randint(1,velocity))
  positionymove.append(random.randint(1,velocity))


font = pygame.font.Font(None, 28)
text = font.render('Starting Twerk... ', True, (100,100,100))
textRect = text.get_rect()
textRect.centerx = screen.get_rect().centerx
textRect.centery = screen.get_rect().centery

screen.blit(backdrop, (0,0))
screen.blit(text, textRect)
pygame.display.update()
game=time.localtime()

while start == True:
  end=time.localtime()
  score= (end[1]-game[1])*3600 + (end[4]-game[4])*60 + end[5]-game[5]
  if score > 1: break

first=True
strtTime=time.localtime()

while not finish or falling:
  screen.blit(backdrop, (0,0))
  for i in range(enemies):
    screen.blit(ballpic,(positionx[i],positiony[i]))
    (mousex,mousey)=mouse.get_pos()
    screen.blit(mouseball,(mousex,mousey))
    display.update()
    strt = time.localtime()

  if first:
    while True:
      end=time.localtime()
      score= (end[3]-strt[3])*3600 + (end[4]-strt[4])*60 + end[5]-strt[5]
      if score > 3: break
    first = False

  if falling:
    for i in range(enemies):
      positionymove[i]=1000
      positionxmove[i]=0


  for i in range(enemies): positionx[i]=positionx[i]+positionxmove[i]
  for i in range(enemies): positiony[i]=min(600,positiony[i]+positionymove[i])

  if falling:
    falling=False
    for posy in positiony:
      if posy<600: falling=True


  if not falling:
    for i in range(enemies):
      for j in range(i+1,enemies):
        if abs(positionx[i]-positionx[j])<20 and abs(positiony[i]-positiony[j])<20:
          temp=positionxmove[i]
          positionxmove[i]=positionxmove[j]
          positionxmove[j]=temp
          temp=positionymove[i]
          positionymove[i]=positionymove[j]
          positionymove[j]=temp

    for i in range(enemies):  
      if positionx[i]>600: positionxmove[i]*=-1
      if positionx[i]<0: positionxmove[i]*=-1
      if positiony[i]>440: positionymove[i]*=-1
      if positiony[i]<0: positionymove[i]*=-1

    for i in range(enemies):
      if abs(positionx[i]-mousex)<40 and abs(positiony[i]-mousey)<40:
        falling = True
        finish = True
        start = False
        endTime=time.localtime()
        score= (endTime[3]-strtTime[3])*3600 + (endTime[4]-strtTime[4])*60 + endTime[5]-strtTime[5]
        break




  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type==KEYUP and event.key==K_ESCAPE:
      finish=True 
      pygame.quit()


game()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I think you wanted to exit the for loop if start was found true right?
Add a break after the assignment for both. You want to do this for most of the loops.

```
start = False
repeat = False
while start == False:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            start = True
            break

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                start = True
                break
```

You can combine some of these conditions, for example

```
    for i in range(enemies):  
      if positionx[i]>600 || positionx[i]<0: positionxmove[i]*=-1
      if positiony[i]>440 || positiony[i]<0: positionymove[i]*=-1
```

Note that positionx and positiony may best be stored together in some datastructure - perhaps a tuple

Something like this

```
  positionxmove.append(random.randint(1,velocity))
  positionymove.append(random.randint(1,velocity))
```

can be reduced to

```
 for p in [positionxmove, positionymove]:
     p.append(random.randint(1,velocity))
```

The idea is to reduce repetition as much as you can.

Combine the loops. for e.g

```
  for i in range(enemies): positionx[i]=positionx[i]+positionxmove[i]
  for i in range(enemies): positiony[i]=min(600,positiony[i]+positionymove[i])
```

Should be

```
  for i in range(enemies): 
      positionx[i]=positionx[i]+positionxmove[i]
      positiony[i]=min(600,positiony[i]+positionymove[i])
```

Also remove all the magic numbers like 600. They should be named with some meaningful names, and those variables/constants should be used instead.

You can reduce some thing such as this

```
          temp=positionxmove[i]
          positionxmove[i]=positionxmove[j]
          positionxmove[j]=temp
          temp=positionymove[i]
          positionymove[i]=positionymove[j]
          positionymove[j]=temp
```

to

```
   for p in [positionxmove, positionymove]:
          p[i], p[j] = p[i],p[i]
```

that is, use parallel assignment for swapping.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment your game is one long "noodle" of code - I would split it into several... err... entities which represent separate activities - intro screen, the main game loop, high scores screen, settings screen, whatever. At their simplest they can be separate functions, but defining some classes would be a bit nicer:

```
class Intro(object):

    def __init__(self):
        # set up stuff for the intro

    def run(self):
        # intro loop

class Game(object):
    ...

intro = Intro()
game = Game()
intro.run()
game.run()
```

With this approach you can add more stuff (high scores screen etc.) without complicating your game loop too much.

I would also consider encapsulating Enemy/Player logic into separate classes.

As a learning exercise - maybe try to rewrite the game so no function/metod is longer than 10 lines.

And add some comments too. A lot of them.